# Bipartitle clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, bipartite

I have a bipartite graph of queries and associated clicked urls. Based on these queries, I want to cluster queries. I am planning to use simple set based formula for determining whether two queries are same or not. My initial input data is in the following format:

```
Url   Queries   
Url1   Q1, Q2, Q3   
Url2   Q1, Q5, Q6
```

I am having a tough time determining the appropriate algorithm to solve this problem.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you using to retrieve data? what programming language?

Comment: **What (algorithms) have you tried?** What did not work, and why?

Comment: Michael: I have all my data in mysql and using ruby/rails to fetch the data. If I can get the logic, I can code it in ruby

Anony: I tried igraph package of R. It has bipartite graph type. However I am having trouble loading the data. Also I am actually interested in some ruby based code.